# Using asp webapi to post a nested resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using mvc webapi to create a REST API and struggling to find an example dealing with POSTs to nested resources.

Basically, I want to `POST` a comment to a blog post using a URL like:

`~/posts/2/comments`

I would also like to be able to send DELETE and `PUTs` to the following

`~/posts/2/comments/5`

What should my route registration look like, and what should my method signature on my `PostsController` look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For nested resources I would suggest that you create very specific routes for the controllers/actions that you want to access.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Posts Routes",
    routeTemplate: "api/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Posts", action="CommentsForPosts" }
);

public HttpResponseMessage CommentsForPosts(int postId, int commentID) {
    //go to work
}
```

There's no convention in the framework for nested resources but routing gives you the flexibility to map your controllers, methods, and URIs however you see fit