# RESTful POST with nested URL on webApi

Tags: rest, post, asp.net-mvc-4

I am suffering from the following problem when trying to perform a POST to create a new REST resource on a nested URL with my own .Net WebApi based REST-service.

Please imagine the following url ***api/parents/{parentId}/children*** on which I want to perform a POST to add another child.

This is very similar to the problem described in: [Using asp webapi to post a nested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145762/using-asp-webapi-to-post-a-nested-resource). But in global.asax I do not succeed to define with *routes.MapHttpRoute(...)* a route which calls a method of my Parents-controller containing the *{parentId}* as well as the Child object to be added/posted, e.g. calling:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddChildToParent(int parentId, Child newChild) {
    //implementation
}
```

(This is also the difference to the answer of the above mentioned question, since it does not provide any object which could be added.)

I was searching the Web, but unfortunately I could not find a solution - probably also, because I could not even find an official documentation of the semantics of the *defaults*-object used as parameter for the *MapHttpRoute()* method.

Can anybody please suggest a working routing definition for my problem or at least post a link to a useful documentation of the *defaults*-object used in *MapHttpRoute()*? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10030485) post may be helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following Web API routing to your registration function. (The registration function by default is passed in `WebApiApplication` on `Application_Start`, which inherits from `System.Web.HttpApplication`, to the function `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(...)`. By default it's defined in the static class `WebApiConfig`.)

Add

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PostChild",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{parentId}/children",
    defaults: new { action = "AddChildToParent" },
    constraints: new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post),
        controller = "Parents"
    }
);
```

to the registration function, where `config` is the `HttpConfiguration` object parameter.

Then via the URL `api/parents/{parentId}/children` the following method in `ParentsController` will be called:

```
public class ParentsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]int parentId, [FromBody] Child child) {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Note that both the `defaults` and the `constraints` parameters in `MapHttpRoute` are anonymous objects with property names corresponding to Web API variable names. As the `action` variable is cannot be set via URL, it gets a default value which points to the web API method in the controller.

The `constraints` object limits the call to the given Regular Expression. In this case it is the fixed controller name, but could also be multiple controllers e.g. by `"(Parents|ParentsAlternative)"`. Only Web API calls with all constraints met will lead to a Controller method being called, here `AddChildToParent`.

The `Child` object here is passed in the HTTP body as JSON, as denoted in the parameter attribute `[FromBody]`.